# Does retopology require "transfer texture to new UVs"?

Tags: uv

I wanted to have a low poly version of a perfectly rigged and textured model.

I asked somebody to teach me this retopology because I felt that there was much to take care of.

I was thinking that the UV islands should be kept at their original locations so that the textures still work.

Now my teacher told me that he had to "transfer" the textures because of the new UVs.

Can anybody confirm that this is true and that I'm wrong in my assumption that if we just keep the original UV island locations, we can simply keep working with the original textures without any problems?

Or am I missing something here?

Thank you very much!

Edit: I asked the person to stay very close to the original edge flow. If he did that, shouldn't it be possible to just use the very same textures without "transferring" anything?

Comment: UVs are uniquely bound to the vertices of a mesh. If the topology changes then you need to  create new UVs.

Comment: @cegaton Yes, sure, but isn't it possible to keep as close to the original edge flow so that one can still work with just the very same textures? I thought that this could / would be possible.